# Не хватает памяти для обработки больших массивов

Tags: php

На виртуальном сервере не хватает памяти для обработки некоторых файлов, хотя на локальном всё в порядке.
Ошибка:
`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77 bytes)`

В php.ini увеличивал до 999М - не помогает. 
Обрабатываемые файлы - XML файлы,выгрузка из 1C, некоторые до 350 000 строк.
Ошибку выдаёт нижеприведённый скрипт, он конвертирует объекты в массивы.
Можно ли ещё решить проблему прописав в конфигурационных файлах больше памяти, или есть возможность адаптировать скрипт?

```
function simpleXmlObjectToArray( $xmlObject, $out = array () ){
  foreach ( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node )
      $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) || is_array($node) )
      ? simpleXmlObjectToArray ( $node )
      : $node;

  return $out;
}
```

Comment: у вас на виртуальном сервере сколько памяти то? большие XML в память обычно не загружают целиком а используют потоковые парсеры.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```